# Apps Script: Insert rows when cell is empty

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to automate a sheet using a for-loop that inserts rows in a specific range when a cell in the range is empty. So far, it sort of works in the sense that rows are added, however not always in the right places. As the for-loop runs its course, it seems to add rows to the sheet based on the version before the for-loop began, ergo the sheet does not update as the for-loop makes changes, ergo rows are inserted haphazardly. Is there a way to insert rows in the correct places? My friend suggested recursion methods but I'm not too sure I understand what he means. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('operationsTriggerFranz')
       .forSpreadsheet('1nbqO5aIXitPma_Esz1uIltowAvU0NRhHN4J8yypYdcY')
       .onEdit()
       .create();
}

function operationsTriggerFranz(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inOperations = ss.getSheetByName('Operations');
  var inGeneral = ss.getSheetByName('General');
  var monthlyKPI = e.value;
  var operationsKPIs = inOperations.getRange("D5:D42");
  var operationsKPIList = operationsKPIs.getValues();
  var editLocation = e.range.getSheet();
 
  if (editLocation.getName() === "Operations"){
      if (monthlyKPI.indexOf("1") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("2") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("3") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("4") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("5") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("6") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("7") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("8") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("9") >= 0 || monthlyKPI.indexOf("10") >= 0) {
        for (var row = 0; row<=operationsKPIList.length; row++) {
          if (operationsKPIList[row] == "i miss school")  
            inOperations.insertRowBefore(row+4);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, can you please include the code in the question and **not** as a picture? @otomenohoshi

Comment: Moreover, can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please post the code directly into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Hint: Were not going to look at your code from an image.  Post it in the question.

Comment: Hi, everyone. Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow. :( I've formatted my code into the question and removed the photos. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You also need to add a to the insertrow line.

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness! This one worked! I just had to change .getRange(row+6+a++,5).setValue("KPI Here") to .getRange(row+5+a++,5).setValue("KPI Here"). But now there is another problem. Since my range is specified as E5:E16, it doesn't account for the new cells that are added whenever the function runs. Is there a way to possibly add these new cells into the range? Thank you so much for this, Cooper.

Comment: You can simply update the range in question to match the new values as well: such as `E5:E` @otomenohoshi